# Is there a Unity Unet Spawn CallBack function?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

On the server，I create an obj, and spawn it. But on the client how do I know when the object is spawned? I want to know whether there is a spawn callback function.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:
[Custom Spawning callbacks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetCustomSpawning.html)

Whenever you're using this, you're now responsible for instantiating the new object on all your clients, you can do that with a simple Instantiate() like in the examples given.

Two big caveats however:

- For some reason, spawn callbacks are never called on the host, so if you're doing any initialization for the object in your callback, be aware that on the host you will probably still have to do this after calling Spawn().
- I banged my head a bit against the wall for this one, but it seems that calling RegisterSpawnHandler() also **registers the prefab**, so as incredible as it may sound, if you're calling RegisterPrefab() for the same object in any other place in your code (**including the NetworkManager**), your callbacks will never get called. At least this was my experience in 2017.1.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you can directly get a callback to the spawn function client side, but you could just attach a script inheriting NetworkBehaviour to the spawned object, and add this in the script :

```
public class MySpawnedObject : NetworkBehaviour
{
     void Awake()
     {
          if (!isServer)
             //do what you want with your client
     }
}
```

But do not forget that isServer return true if the current executable is a host, while UNET consider a host to be server AND client, you can also use isClient that will trigger for both hosts and clients.

```
if (isClient)
```

Comment: okay thank you for your reply，I would like to know Unet inside there is no similar callback function, because in the client, I do not know spwan out of the object when generated, the current Unet only know LocalPlayer generated time, public override void OnStartLocalPlayer (), but spwan But not, if you want to add a spwan object! IsServer is a bit less convenient

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand your question then.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any direct way to know that player has spawned at server but You can fire an event from server that can run on each client when you instantiate your player. For this reason you can use ClientRPC attribute

> [ClientRpc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientRpcAttribute.html)- The [*ClientRpc*] attribute is called on the server and
>   executed on all of the clients that are currently connected to the
>   server for a given object. [*ClientRpc*] is most commonly used to notify
>   the clients of game changes like a change in score or that they have
>   died (to play sound and death animations on all players' screens).

Like this script attached to your local player

```
public class MyLocalPlayer: NetworkBehaviour
{
    int counter;
    [ClientRpc]
    public void PlayerSpawned(int extra)
    {
        Debug.Log("a player has spawned");
    }

}
```